# Hover and toggle in basic javascript

Tags: javascript, hover, toggle

I have the following JavaScript code for a simple hover which uses JQuery:

```
$('.product_img_link').hover(function(){
  $(this).prev('.hoverProduct').show();
},function(){
  $(this).prev('.hoverProduct').hide();
});
```

(finds the previous `div` with class `hoverProduct`, and displays it on hover and hides it on mouse out).

How can I write this snippet without JQuery, using only plain JavaScript?

Comment: sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I think he want to convert this to basic javascript without jQuery

Comment: Yes Arun. I want to convert this code in basic javascript without jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.product_img_link');

[].forEach.call(links, function(link) {
  var prev = link.previousSibling;
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    prev.style.display == 'block';
  });
  link.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    prev.style.display == 'none';
  });
});
```

In jQuery `prev` with a selector gets the previous element **only if** it matches the selector. If you want the same behavior in plain JS you can test like this:

```
...
var prev = link.previousSibling;
var hasClass = /\bhoverProduct\b/.test(prev.className);

if (hasClass) {
  // events
}
...
```